# Cancel a close event

Tags: eclipse

I have an editor in Eclipse. When the user chooses to close it, a dialog shall appear with several options. One of them is "Cancel" and should cancel the close event. How can I do that?

The partial code I have so far:

```
    ...
    IEditorPart openEditor = page.openEditor(input, CS_STRINGEDITOR_ID);
    openEditor.getEditorSite().getPage()
        .addPartListener(new IPartListener() {
          public void partOpened(IWorkbenchPart part) {}
          public void partDeactivated(IWorkbenchPart part) {}

          public void partClosed(IWorkbenchPart part) {
            Shell sh = new Shell(cv.getViewSite().getShell());
            // My MessageDialog with the options, one being "cancel"
            CloseDialog closeDialog = new CloseDialog(sh);
            closeDialog.open();
            int returnCode = closeDialog.getReturnCode();
            switch (returnCode) {
            case CloseDialog.CANCEL_ID:
              // Abort the close event and keep the editor alive
              break;
            }
          }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [thread points out](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&goto=307349&) there is no closing event per se.

> Eclipse provides mostly post-activite events, i.e. on `IPartListener2`, `partClosed(*)` is a
>   post-closing event.
>
> You can provide your own dialog on close, but it will only be shown if the
>   editor is dirty at the time it is closed. See [`ISaveablePart2.promptToSaveOnClose()`](http://help.eclipse.org/help32/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/ISaveablePart2.html)

(as presented in the [Prevent that a RCP Editor is closed](http://e-rcp.blogspot.com/2007/09/prevent-that-rcp-editor-is-closed.html))

> However, note that implementing `ISaveablePart2` may lead to many dialogs being opened when you close multiple editors.